# Windows File Server without DC

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Hello everyone: Recently I have got assignment to establish a windows file server, there are only 15 laptops. I am not a network/server guy but familiar with basics.

1- All clients(win7,10) are connected with a simple wifi-router (DHCP enabled)
2- I have installed windows server 2012 r2 standard ED

What I want to achieve is: I want to share folders where clients can access folders with credentials without domain controller.

Because all 15 employees have laptops and they carry with it. If I setup Domain Controller then I guess I have to assign static ip address and whenever they will leave office they won't be able to access login in their window account? right? If they can access then they won't be able to connect to different wifi internet at their homes because their laptops are configured with static ip.

How can I achieve this task? I just want simple file sharing with credential. All systems including server will be connected with router for internet access.

One more thing if i setup Active Directory do I need to create DC as well?

I would appreciate if someone can help me in this regard.

Comment: So many things in this question tell me that you need to hire a pro.

Comment: Sorry Gregl: we dont need to hire a pro for that. I just need help to setup simple File Server on Windows 2012 Server with credential. Keeping in mind that all laptops are connected with dhcp enable wifi internet router.

Comment: `One more thing if i setup Active Directory do I need to create DC as well?` This line alone tells me you need a pro, or at the vary least that you need to do some research.

Comment: What if i don't setup AD. Can I still establish File Server with Credential for same network users?

Comment: You don't have to use AD, but you **should**. There's no good reason to not use it. And agreed with Greg - hire someone to come in for a few hours and at least help you sort out the basics of this implementation.

Comment: Actually Iam the MIS person and boss don't understand these and won't allow to hire. I will Google but want to confirm is it possible to establish simple file server with credentials? Where all users and server is connected with DHCP router. I have done simple sharing in two win7 pcs where both pc are connected with router (DHCP enabled). I wish I could done in server 2012 with credential to access folders.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question directly, yes you can create the scenario you desire without Active Directory. You would need to create local user accounts for all users on the file server and then add them to the share and folder permissions. You would then either need to map the drives on each machine and save the credentials or they would need to re-enter credentials each time the share was accessed.

However, as the other commentors alluded to, you probably should at least talk to a pro first. The way you are going about it is difficult and you are making it harder on yourself with many incorrect assumptions.

- You don't need any static addresses on user machines whether you are in an AD environment or a workgroup. The laptops should be set to retrieve their IPs via DHCP whether they are on a domain or not for the reasons you stated (so they work on other networks too).
- If you were to setup Active Directory and join the laptops to the domain, they could still login when not able to contact a DC. Once they authenticate to the DC, their credentials will be cached by default and they can login to their machines while offline using the same credentials without issue.
- Finally, by definition, a domain controller is required for Active Directory.

If everything and is on the same Active Directory domain your credential management and access to the file server is going to be much simpler. Trying to manage that without AD is asking for headaches and time wasted.

Despite your position, your boss should not expect you to know everything necessary to run your organizations IT, unless it was somehow misrepresented to him that you did. Hiring a pro will ultimately save your time and save your organization in time and productivity. You should make the case that doing it right to begin with will save a lot of time and hassle in the long term.

Comment: thank you learley: ur ans helped me alot. If i configure DC/AD and join the clients to domain. As clients will be connected with wifi-router(DHCP enabled) as well as the server will also be connected and if it will work fine then I will Google/Youtube.??